# How to \n after an amount of X time

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

I am a beginner in python programming.
I need to make a Tic Tac Toe game but where the user can input the number of the X's and the Y's.

This is my code:

```
    def printboards():
    board_s1 = " _ "
    board_s2 = "| |"
    board_s3 = " _ "
    backspace = ("\n")
    print board_s1
    print board_s2
    print board_s3
    return
boardX = raw_input("How many X boards do you want? (insert 1 more than you want) > ")
boardY = raw_input("How many Y boards do you want? (insert 1 more than you want) > ")
for xx in range(1,int(boardX)):
    printboards()
    for yy in range(1,int(boardY)):
        printboards()
```

But every time I run the program I am getting this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WghMW.png)

And my second problem is that if I input 3 in BoardX and BoardY I am getting just 6 boxes and not 3x3 boxes.

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to python programming. The problem with the newline is, that every `print` is done in a new line. So in your case if you call `printboards()` multiple times, it will draw all the boxes under another.

You are getting only 6 boxes because the python function `range()` uses a 0-index meaning that it starts counting at 0. If you would use `range(0,int(boardX))` and `range(0,int(boardY))` it would give you the right number of boxes. However, if you want to start at 0, you gan just discard the 0 and use `range(int(boardX))`.

If you are using a function to draw the board, just let it do the entire thing:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#The function now takes the dimensions of the board in x and y as arguments
def printboards(x,y):
    # This results in y rows of boxes
    for i in range(y):
        # with x * "some text" you can multiply text
        print x*" _  "
        print x*"| | "
        print x*" ‾  " 

boardX = raw_input("How many X boards do you want? > ")
boardY = raw_input("How many Y boards do you want? > ")
printboards(int(boardX), int(boardY))
```

One more thing: I also added the `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` because i used a special character for the bottom of the box.

Hope I could help.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but when I load the program instead of the bottom of the box I have тА╛and I added # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Comment: Maybe that's a copy paste problem. Just Google "overline" and copy paste it again from the Wikipedia article into the script.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work by modifying the function to pass a parameter to control the width.

`def printboards(x):
    board_s1 = " _ " * x
    board_s2 = "| |" * x
    board_s3 = " - " * x
    backspace = ("\n")
    print board_s1
    print board_s2 
    print board_s3`

Removed the insert one more than you want

```
boardX = raw_input("How many X boards do you want?  > ")
boardY = raw_input("How many Y boards do you want?  > ")
```

in the for loop added the extra one as int(boardX)+1 to control the proper depth

```
for xx in range(1,int(boardX)+1):
    #int(boardY) parameter controls the width
    printboards(int(boardY))
```